# isset is not working on submit

Tags: php, html, web

This is a 5-star rating form and I am trying to make it work.

```
<div class="stars">
  <form>
    <input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star" value="5"/>
    <label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
    <input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star" value="4"/>
    <label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
    <input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star" value="3"/>
    <label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
    <input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star" value="2"/>
    <label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
    <input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star" value="1"/>
    <label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
    <button class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>

  </form>
</div>
```

When I press the submit button nothing happens. The code does not move into the if statement, though it should since submit is not longer null.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $rating = $_POST['star'];
    echo "hello";
    echo $rating;
}
?>
```

Comment: You are not using POST, the default method is GET.

Comment: set form attr like `<form method="post" action="" >

Comment: Use this `<form method="post" action="" >` and on php code use `if(isset($_POST['star']))` it will work.

Comment: @BibhudattaSahoo Done it worked. Thank you, it seems that tutorial i was watching had this as error in it's code and never corrected it. If you want post this as an answer and I will check it.

Comment: @Syarx you are welcome then close your question by accepting my answer.

Answer (score 2):

set form `method=post`
if html and php code in same page use
set form `action=""` otherwise use
set form `action=".php file"`

**for ex:`<form method="post" action=" or .php file">`**

Answer (score 1):

You just missed to put form **method** and **action** in form.
Use this

`<form method="post" action="" >`

and on php code use

```
if(isset($_POST['star']))
```

it will work

Answer (score 0):

To use super global variable $_POST, u need to specify method attribute to the form tag with submit button.
Change your form tag and your submit button tag to :

```
<div class="stars">
<form method="POST" name="starRatingForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
<input class="star star-5" id="star-5" type="radio" name="star" value="5"/>
<label class="star star-5" for="star-5"></label>
<input class="star star-4" id="star-4" type="radio" name="star" value="4"/>
<label class="star star-4" for="star-4"></label>
<input class="star star-3" id="star-3" type="radio" name="star" value="3"/>
<label class="star star-3" for="star-3"></label>
<input class="star star-2" id="star-2" type="radio" name="star" value="2"/>
<label class="star star-2" for="star-2"></label>
<input class="star star-1" id="star-1" type="radio" name="star" value="1"/>
<label class="star star-1" for="star-1"></label>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**`isset()`**](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) checks if a variable has a value including `( False , 0 , or empty string)` , but not NULL. Returns TRUE if variable exists otherwise returns `FALSE`.

On the other hand the [**`empty()`**](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function checks if the variable has an `empty value, empty string , 0, NULL ,or False`. Returns `FALSE` if variable has a `non-empty` and `non-zero` value.

### Example

```
if(!empty($_POST['star'])){
     ....
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to set *method* and *action* attributes in the form tag.

```
 <form method='post' action='page.php'>
```